# Counting Integers in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this reproducible example below where I try to count integers. I have a "Start"-button, a "Reset"-button, and a "Stop"-button. So the process should look like that: 1,2,3 -Stop- -Start- 4,5,6...

Unfortunately, it looks like that: 1,2,3 -Stop- -Start- 5,7,9 -Stop- -Start- 12,15,18 ... So each time I press Stop and Start or Stop - Reset - Start it will add 1 to the increase.

Can someone see the issue in the code for that problem? Thanks.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(
    titlePanel("XXX"),
    hr(style="border-color: grey;"),
    sidebarLayout(
        # panel with all inputs
        sidebarPanel(
                   # start / reset buttons on same row
                     fluidRow(
                         column(7,uiOutput("resetbutton")),
                         column(5,uiOutput("startbutton"))
                     ),
                     hr(style="border-color: grey;"),
                     fluidRow(
                         column(7,actionButton("stop","Stop")),
                         column(3,actionButton("start","Start"))
                     )
        ),
        # plot panel
        mainPanel(
            
            # tab layout
            tabsetPanel(
                
                tabPanel("XXX",
                         
                         
                         # visual data on same row
                         fluidRow(
                             column(3,textOutput("Count"))
                         )
                         
                )
            )
        )   
    )
)
```

server.R

```
server<-function(input,output){
    
    Val <- reactiveValues()
    Val$count<- 1

    # dynamic reset button label
    output$resetbutton<-renderUI({
        actionButton("reset",label= "Reset")
    })
    
    
    forward<-function(){
        
        Val$count <- Val$count + 1 
        
    }
    
    
    session<-reactiveValues()
    session$timer<-reactiveTimer(Inf)
    
    observeEvent(input$start,{
        session$timer<-reactiveTimer(1000)
        observeEvent(session$timer(),{
            forward()
        })
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$stop,{
        session$timer<-reactiveTimer(Inf)
    })
    
    ## when reset button is pressed (set everything to original values)
    observeEvent(input$reset,{
        Val$count<- 1
    })
    
    
    ##Count Output
    output$Count <-renderText({
        paste("Count:",Val$count)
    })
    
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, as there have been a lot of questions including this recently: where is it suggested or demonstrated to use nested `observe` blocks? I don't understand what is expected to happen in the inner `observe` that will not happen within *just* the outer `observe`.

Comment: @r2evans: I think the intend is to protect some expressions from being invalidated by certain inputs/ reactives. But I too think that it should be avoided. Instead of nesting `observeEvent`s `observe()` in combination with `isolate()` is clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: @TimTeaFan, perhaps, but ... the *intent* of `observeEvent` is to only trigger on specific events, so to nest it for the sake of inferred isolation of reactive components inside of it is misguided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a cleaner way of doing this is to use `invalidateLater` combined with a minimal control flow that checks a flag `Val$run` if the clock is running or not.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(ui =fluidPage(
  titlePanel("XXX"),
  hr(style="border-color: grey;"),
  sidebarLayout(
    # panel with all inputs
    sidebarPanel(
      # start / reset buttons on same row
      fluidRow(
        column(7,uiOutput("resetbutton")),
        column(5,uiOutput("startbutton"))
      ),
      hr(style="border-color: grey;"),
      fluidRow(
        column(7,actionButton("stop","Stop")),
        column(3,actionButton("start","Start"))
      )
    ),
    # plot panel
    mainPanel(
      
      # tab layout
      tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel("XXX",
                 
                 
                 # visual data on same row
                 fluidRow(
                   column(3,textOutput("Count"))
                 )
                 
        )
      )
    )   
  )
),

server = function(input,output) {

  Val <- reactiveValues()
  Val$count<- 1
  Val$run <- FALSE
  
  # dynamic reset button label
  output$resetbutton<-renderUI({
    actionButton("reset",label= "Reset")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$start,{
    Val$run <- TRUE
  })

  observe({
    if (Val$run) {
      isolate(Val$count <- Val$count + 1)
      invalidateLater(1000)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$stop,{
    Val$run <- FALSE
  })
  
  ## when reset button is pressed (set everything to original values)
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    Val$count<- 1
  })
  
  
  ##Count Output
  output$Count <-renderText({
    paste("Count:",Val$count)
  })
  
})
```

We can also make the approach with `reactiveTimer` work:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(ui =fluidPage(
  titlePanel("XXX"),
  hr(style="border-color: grey;"),
  sidebarLayout(
    # panel with all inputs
    sidebarPanel(
      # start / reset buttons on same row
      fluidRow(
        column(7,uiOutput("resetbutton")),
        column(5,uiOutput("startbutton"))
      ),
      hr(style="border-color: grey;"),
      fluidRow(
        column(7,actionButton("stop","Stop")),
        column(3,actionButton("start","Start"))
      )
    ),
    # plot panel
    mainPanel(
      
      # tab layout
      tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel("XXX",
                 
                 
                 # visual data on same row
                 fluidRow(
                   column(3,textOutput("Count"))
                 )
                 
        )
      )
    )   
  )
),

server = function(input,output) {

  Val <- reactiveValues()
  Val$count<- 0
  
  # dynamic reset button label
  output$resetbutton<-renderUI({
    actionButton("reset",label= "Reset")
  })

  session<-reactiveValues()
  session$timer<-reactiveTimer(Inf)
  
  observeEvent(input$start, {
    session$timer <- reactiveTimer(1000)
    Val$count<- Val$count -1
  })
  
  observe({
    session$timer()
    isolate(Val$count <- Val$count + 1)
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$stop,{
    session$timer<-reactiveTimer(Inf)
    Val$count<- Val$count -1
  })
  
  ## when reset button is pressed (set everything to original values)
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    Val$count<- 1
  })
  
  
  ##Count Output
  output$Count <-renderText({
    paste("Count:",Val$count)
  })

})
```